# block statement surrounding arrow body error with map

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I understand this question has been asked before, but I can't figure out the syntax that the linter wants in my current situation.

I understand I need to remove the block statement brackets but cannot figure out how to refactor to get it to work and also pass lint:

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      paymentSchedule.map((payment) => {
        return (
            <div>{payment.description}</div>
        );
      })
    }
  </div>
);
```

This produces the following lint error:

> Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using arrow function:

**1-** Block body: `() => { /*other logic*/ return(....)}`

**2-** Concise body: `() => (....) // implied "return"`

---

In your case block body is not required, because you just want to return on `div` without any other logic or calculation so directly use the concise body.

Like this:

```
return (
    <div>
      {
         paymentSchedule.map(payment => <div key={payment.description}>{payment.description}</div> )
      }
    </div>
);
```

**Suggestion**: Assign the unique key to each element otherwise it will also throw the warning.